# Правильный роутинг в Angular.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular2, angular-routing

Есть уже заранее написанное веб-приложение, хочу переписать весь фронт на ангуларе. Решил использовать Angular 2, чтобы сейчас потрениться и когда выйдет стабильная версия иметь какой-то опыт разработки на нем. Первое с чем столкнулся, это роутинг, когда мы заходим в приложение `http://mybestapp.com/` грузится страница index.html которая загружает сам аngular. Когда мы с главной страницы куда-то ходим, например жмем на ссылку `/getUser/123`, сервак отдает json и мы рисуем данные в браузере. Но, если мы сразу перейдем по ссылке `http://mybestapp.com/getUser/123` в новом окне, мы получим просто json строку (это нормальное поведение сервера в ответ на такой get-запрос). Из способов, как выйти из данной ситуации, я придумал пока только один - смотреть в контроллере `getUser` на сервере (и вообще во всех контроллерах), был ли передан заголовок `x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest`, и если не был, то редиректить юзера на главную страницу (`http://mybestapp.com/`), вернее даже не редиректить, а просто, тупо взять и отдать ему ему содержание главной странички, но при этом остаться на `/getUser/123`. А вот если `x-requested-with` был передан, тогда мы отдадим json. Тут еще следует учесть что есть всякие страницы `404` и прочие ошибки.

Расскажите пожалуйста, правильный ли мой подход (вот мне кажется что нет), и как правильно решить эту задачу?

Comment: А не лучше в таком случае разделить *front* и *back* отдельно? Чтобы *backend* отдавал только по api *json*, тогда роутинг фронта будет работать нормально без всяких дополнительных игр с просмотром заголовков.

Comment: @Moonvvell, опишите вкратце, как это должно выглядеть. Какое поведение будет в случае с этим примером что я описал, а именно прямой переход по ссылке `http://mybestapp.com/getUser/123`

Comment: Если там обычное *API* например делаете ему адрес `api.mybestapp.com/getUser/123` или `mybestapp.com/api/getUser/123` . Это будет два независимые приложения - *api* отдает данные, а ангуляр приложение принимает с апи данные, и уже переходит по своему роутингу, роутинг ангуляра никаким образом не будет соприкасаться с *backend* роутингом.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы разделите ваше приложение на backend и frontend, то все запросы к серверу (к страницам) вы должны перенаправлять на index.html, а роутинг angular уже сам разрулит. В сервисах [angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) вы обращаетесь к api сервера, которые уже и отдаёт данные.

Comment: Именно об этом я и говорил в вопросе, только не был уверен что это правильно

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать проще, добавьте в импорт роутера в главном модуле useHash: true
`RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })` 
в этом случает все урл будут вида http://mybestapp.com/#/getUser/123
и никаких дополнительных танцев с бубном вокруг сервера не понадобится