# Настройка роутов express + angular 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular2

Делаю проект на ангуляр 2 + express. Немогу правильно настроить роуты на сервере. Главная страница загружается хорошо; перехожу на внутреннею тоже все хорошо. Но когда перезагружаю страницу, то получаю только данные (json) без фронт-енда

вот так выглядит настройка роутов

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../')); //получаю фронт-енд, поэтому пути находится index.html

app.get('/place/info/1', function(req, res) {
   res.json({
     id: "df",
     name: "name"
   });
});
```

что нужно сделать, чтобы получать индекс при любых роутах и при этом получать свой json?

Comment: самый простой вариант - сделать так, чтобы адреса не совпадали

Comment: на сколько это правильный подход? если ли ещё решения этой проблемы? в какую сторону посмотреть? Спасибо.

Comment: смотря что считать правильным подходом. Альтернативный вариант может быть [проверкой, что это ajax запрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945118/detecting-ajax-requests-on-nodejs-with-express) и в случае не аякса - возвращать страницу, а не json

Comment: то есть, такой вариант вполне подходит для реальных проектов (получать данные по раззным путям)? Сорри, за глупые вопросы, просто уже несколько дней пытаюсь решить эту проблему и хочу полностью с ней разобраться.

Comment: _то есть, такой вариант вполне подходит для реальных проектов_ почему нет? сейчас можно вообще выделить все метод которые возвращают json в какой нибудь api, чтобы к ним можно было обращаться не только с твоего сайта, а сама страница отдельно

Comment: спасибо большое!) очень помогли.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500276/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b2-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично [похожему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500276/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B2-angular-js)
добавьте в импорт роутера в главном модуле useHash: true
`RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })` 
и ничего на сервере настраивать не придется

Comment: и зачем в урлу добавлять хэш?

Comment: Чтобы при перезагрузке страницы в браузере всегда подгружался индекс, т.к. route часть будет после хеша. Или я неправильно понял суть проблему?

Comment: так это не практично, оставлять хэш в урле.. от него всегда избавляются